# Basic HTTP Authentication not including JSON in header? (Backbone.js to Rails server)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js to create a pure JS front-end for my rails app using a JSON api.

The backbone.js model URL looks like this:

```
window.MedicationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Medication,
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/medication_options'
});
```

CRUD works fine with this. It's sending requests to my server with an "application/JSON" content type.

But I needed to add authentication for the API and my rails app is using Authlogic so I added this:

```
  before_filter :require_user

     def require_http_auth_user
        return true if current_user
        authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |email, password|
          email = email.gsub("_at_", "@") if email.include?("_at_")
          if @current_user = User.find_by_email(email)
            @current_user.valid_password?(password)
          else
            false
          end
        end
      end
```

And a typical CRUD method in rails looks like this:

```
  def update
    @medication_option = MedicationOption.find(params[:id])
    if @medication_option.update_attributes(params[:medication_option])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated medication."
    end
    respond_with @medication_option
  end
```

So in my Backbone.js model I added "username:password" to the url:

```
window.MedicationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Medication,
    url: 'http://username:password@localhost:3000/medication_options'
});
```

The authentication works fine with the appropriate credentials, but for some reason all of the Backbone.js requests are interpreted by the Rails server as HTML instead of JSON.

For some reason during an Basic HTTP authentication, the JSON header gets lost in the mix.

So if I explicitly add ".json" to the end of the URL like this:

```
window.MedicationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Medication,
    url: 'http://username:password@localhost:3000/medication_options.json'
});
```

I can get basic GET requests to work.

But when I do CRUD it doesn't work because it appends the ID to the end of the URL, so it errors:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/medication_options.json/41516")
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I've never used Authlogic so I'm not sure if you can do this or not, but can you just put the username and password in the request header instead? Maybe that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .json should always be at the end of the url to be interpreted as json:

```
/medication_options/41516.json
```

You can edit the Model url as well as the collection URL if needed to put the json at the right place.

The root problem is why it doesn't get processed as json in the first place. If you are using rails 3 do you have:

```
respond_to :js
```

or

```
respond_to :json
```

to match your respond_with and make sure your controller accepts this kind of format (otherwise rails would return 406 error by default)?

Comment: The respond_with method hands all of that. It was return json fine until I added the basic http auth.

Comment: Why would you need to auth every request? I would do a normal html form for the auth and then use the session created to load the data. Html login form then a redirection to you backbone app. When the ajax calls fail, then you redirect back to your login page.

Comment: It's going to be a native mobile app so I can't do redirects like that. But I am going to ditch basic HTTP and authenticate using cookies (via a JSON request). Thanks

Comment: I have HTTP authentication enabled on my server too, wouldn't it be insecure to send user and pass in simple plain JS?

Guys can you please suggest a clean way to work with backbone and my REST server that's protected by HTTP Auth?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Document.js, but in looking through the docs it seems you can override `url` and return the result of a function instead of giving it a literal string value. Could you add the `.json` to the end of the url string that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 _.extend(Medication, 
    {extension:'.json',
     url:function() {
          var base = getUrl(this.collection);
          if (this.isNew()) return base + this.extension;
          return (base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/')
                  + this.id + this.extension);
        }
    });
```